# Format string from database into a url link with react, react-router, react-bootstrap-table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-bootstrap-table

So I am using react 16.13, react-router 5.2, and react-bootstrap-table 4.1.5. I am getting a database item that will have a basic URL (example.com) as part of the return. I am using a function to format the URL for consumption within react-bootstrap-table by using its dataFormat prop and want to be able to click it and be directed outside of the app. Thing is I can't seem to get it to work.

Any ideas as to how I can get this done because what I have isn't working and I'm out of ideas.

Thank you for any help you can provide.

**TableHeaderColumn**
without the dataFormat, this pulls the data from DB correctly and just presents it as a string

```
<TableHeaderColumn
                dataField="domain_url"
                dataSort
                dataFormat={dataFormat.urlFormatter}
              >
```

**dataFormat**

```
function urlFormatter(cell) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Route
        path="/external"
        component={() => {
          window.location = { cell };
          return null;
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Route from react-router only established the route. It doesn't present anything that would be clickable. You would want to render a <a href>.

Comment: im routing within the react app. the <a href> returns  localhost:3000/example.com#/admin/sites to the address bar instead of example.com

Answer (score 0):

> format the URL for consumption within react-bootstrap-table by using
> its dataFormat prop and want to be able to click it and be directed
> outside of the app

There is no need to use `window.location` here. You can render an anchor tag with the `URL` you fetched from the server as its `href` attribute since you are being "directed outside of the app".

```
function urlFormatter(cell) {
    return <a href={cell}>{cell}</a>;
}
```

If you are routing within the app, you can look into using the [`Link`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Link) component from `react-router-dom`. You can use the same logic I provided, but with `Link`, you should use the `to` attribute to describe your route

CodeSandBox: https://codesandbox.io/s/so-react-bootstrap-table-dataformat-6kew3

Comment: thing is the way the app is structured this is what ends up happening when i do that

Comment: So i am routing within the app so using <a href just leads to http://localhost:3000/example.com#/admin/sites. so link seems like it would work but <Link to={cell}>{cell}</Link>; still routs within app

Comment: then i guess the only explanation is the database is returning the `localhost:3000/` part along with your URL because if you'll look at my CodeSandBox, it clearly works. I suggest to just remove that via [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) or even better is if you somehow refactor that incorrect data in the database